# Is there a way to implement fmu export to an c++ based simulation software to use fmi?

Tags: python, c++, export, fmi

I have a simulation software (self written) based in c++ and a simulation software (self written) based in  python.
Goal: Co-Simulation of these two software packages

Question: Is there a way to export c++ code to a fmu file. I know there is the FMU SDK package, but I do not think that it serves my needs, if I understood it correctly.

Maybe someone already has some experience creating a fmu file from a self-written c++ code.

If the FMU SDK is already the key for my problem, I have troubles to understand, how it actually works, so I would be very grateful for Your help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you do not want to re-implement the whole FMI Standard, the FMU SDK is exactly what you need for this task. Maybe you can point out the specific problems you have with the FMU SDK?

Comment: Thats good to hear. My problem is that I do not get how I bundle my c++ code into a fmu. Could you maybe provide me with a short example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The FMU SDK ships with several examples... It is a little complex to see through it, but in principal the only files that need to be adapted are (assuming you start from the bouncing ball example): 

    ./fmu20/src/models/bouncingBall/modelDescription_me.xml
    ./fmu20/src/models/bouncingBall/bouncingBall.c

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CMake sources from [PythonFMU](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU) as a reference on how to do this. Internally PythonFMU works by wrapping a C++ library that utilizes the Python C API into an FMU. You could replace the use of the Python C API with your own code. This project uses CPPFMU, which IMO is easier to understand than FMU SDK.

PS: I'm one of the PythonFMU authors.

Additionally, [here](https://github.com/open-simulation-platform/cpp-fmus) is a set of plain C++ demo FMUs using CPPFMU.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [FMICodeGenerator](https://github.com/fmi-tools/FMICodeGenerator).